# Comparing parsed XML with a string

Tags: c#, xml, linq, parsing, linq-to-xml

I'm developing a web service that will receive a XML string and will compare with the internalName string. I'm using LINQ to parse the XML (and I think I'm doing it correctly) but I'm not sure how to compare the "value" withinternalName, per example.

```
    [WebMethod]
    public string WMCompare (string xml, string internalName)
    {
        XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Load(xml);

        var result = from ele in xmlDoc.Descendants("property")
                     select new
                     {
                         key = (string)ele.Element("key"),
                         value = (string)ele.Element("value")
                     };
        foreach (var i in result)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you for your attention and I'm sorry about the newbie question. It's my first time working with XML.

Comment: Would it be challenging to create a model to bind the xml to? Then you can just deserialize the XML into the object and have easy access to all it's properties.

Comment: Which Node/Attribute value you want to compare with "internalName" ? Is it the "key" or "value" ?

Answer (score 0):

Considering that you are comparing string with value:

```
var newResult = result.Where(r => r.value.Equals(internalName))
```

Alternatively, you may also compare while parsing your XML:

```
var result1 = from ele in doc.Descendants("property")
              where ele.HasElements && ele.Element("value") != null && ele.Element("value").Equals(internalName)
              select new
              {
                  key = (string)ele.Element("key"),
                  value = (string)ele.Element("value")
              };
```